# Listing Json data with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, database

so i would like to list the first value of users json i get from making an rest api call with javascript so that the response is like this :

```
"XXX-XXX", "DDD-DDD", "KKK-KKK", "UUU-UUU"
```

Json Data from API call:

```
   users:{
   "XXX-XXX":{
      "Info":{
         "ID":"08",
         "Created": "2021-07-10",
         "Plan": "Basic"}},
   "DDD-DDD":{
       "Info":{
          "ID":"04",
          "Created": "2021-07-11",
          "Plan": "Prime"}}
      },
   "KKK-KKK":{
       "Info":{
          "ID":"02",
          "Created": "2021-07-11",
          "Plan": "Prime"}}
      },
   "UU-UUU":{
       "Info":{
          "ID":"13",
          "Created": "2021-07-11",
          "Plan": "Prime"}}
      }
    }
```

Comment: [`Object.keys(users)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Comment: Is that the format coming from the API?
if you check it there's some error in terms of formatting there's some exceeded curly braces. you need to format it properly first then use Object.keys(data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Object.keys() you will get the result that you want into an array.

```js
let users = {
    "XXX-XXX": {
        "Info": {
            "ID": "08",
            "Created": "2021-07-10",
            "Plan": "Basic"
        }
    },
    "DDD-DDD": {
        "Info": {
            "ID": "04",
            "Created": "2021-07-11",
            "Plan": "Prime"
        }
    },
    "KKK-KKK": {
        "Info": {
            "ID": "02",
            "Created": "2021-07-11",
            "Plan": "Prime"
        }
    },
    "UU-UUU": {
        "Info": {
            "ID": "13",
            "Created": "2021-07-11",
            "Plan": "Prime"
        }
    }
}

let result = Object.keys(users)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

//to get the attributes as array:

Object.keys(your_json_object)

Answer (score 1):

Do this users[Object.keys(users)[0]]

Answer (score 1):

```
const users = {
    "XXX-XXX": {
        "Info": {
            "ID": "08",
            "Created": "2021-07-10",
            "Plan": "Basic"
        }
    },
    "DDD-DDD": {
        "Info": {
            "ID": "04",
            "Created": "2021-07-11",
            "Plan": "Prime"
        }
    },
    "KKK-KKK": {
        "Info": {
            "ID": "02",
            "Created": "2021-07-11",
            "Plan": "Prime"
        }
    },
    "UU-UUU": {
        "Info": {
            "ID": "13",
            "Created": "2021-07-11",
            "Plan": "Prime"
        }
    }
}

console.log('"' + Object.keys(users).join('", "') + '"');
```